# Usage of ML models and DL models for text data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I am newbie to NLP ,
I was  going through the some of the Kaggle notebooks then I got little bit confused. some of them are using ML models text classification and text regression problems and for same problems some of them are using Deep learning models.

I don't understand In what basis they are using ML models and DL models.
Cloud you please any one clarify this Question.

Comment: Deep learning models are a subset of machine learning (ML) models. Are you asking why some use deep learning for text and others don't?

Comment: yes Nayef, That's my question.

Comment: It's difficult to answer in general: even outside the question of DL vs. traditional ML, why one chooses a particular type of ML model depends on many things: some ML methods are known to work better with specific tasks or with specific data characteristics for example. In general DL methods tend to perform better but require more training data and more computational power, so they are not necessarily optimal. Since you're starting with NLP, I would encourage you to start with traditional (non DL) methods and move on to DL methods once you're more comfortable.

Comment: Thanks Erwan for advice